# Conditional SQL Where Clause returning different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL table with the following values

```
Id, EmployeeId, CompletionDate  
1,   100,        NULL  
2,   100,        1/1/2019  
3,   101,        NULL  
4,   102,        1/1/2019
```

I like to return an Id for each employeeId where there is a NULL CompletionDate first only. If no NULL date but a CompletionDate NOT NULL secondly.

Expected Results

```
1, 100, NULL  
3, 101, NULL  
4, 102, 1/1/2019
```

What would be the where clause look like for this?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Database is SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with `CASE WHEN` `Order by`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT EmployeeId,CompletionDate
FROM (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY CASE WHEN CompletionDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
    from T 
) t1
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0ddfa/4/0)**:

```
| EmployeeId | CompletionDate |
|------------|----------------|
|        100 |         (null) |
|        101 |         (null) |
|        102 |       1/1/2019 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method uses `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.CompletionDate is null or
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId and
                        t2.CompletionDate is null
                 );
```

Or aggregation:

```
select EmployeeId,
       (case when count(*) = count(CompletionDate)  -- no nulls
             then max(CompletionDate)
        end) as CompletionDate
from t
group by EmployeeId;
```